# I have a TypeScript compilation error with 'openui5' since the update from Angular 16 to 17

Tags: angular, typescript, sapui5, angular17

In angular16 everything works fine. I have `"@types/openui5" : "1.40.4"` in my dev-dependencies. In the `tsconfig.json` there is following configured:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "openui5"
    ],
     .
     .
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```bash
Error: error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'openui5'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'openui5' specified in compilerOptions
```

and many `doesn't exist` errors like:

```bash
error TS2339: Property 'getCore' does not exist on type 'typeof ui'.

55       sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage(this.getSapLanguage());
                ~~~~~~~
```

or `no exported` errors like:

```bash
error TS2694: Namespace 'sap.ui' has no exported member 'base'.

1246         static getMetadata(): sap.ui.base.Metadata;
                                          ~~~~
```

After updating to Angular17 which requires Typescript 5.2 or higher I got this errors. In Angular16 there was Typescript 4.9 configured.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I've got it. The root cause are changes in TS 5.1: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-1.html#typeroots-are-consulted-in-module-resolution

So I had to delete the `typeRoots`-section from the `compilerOptions` within the `tsconfig.json` and everything works fine again.